# NOOB Question: Is there away to keep electrons constantly flowing?

Tags: current, constant-current, electron

What i mean by this is we run things on lets say a battery, but eventually it runs out. Is there away we can have electrons stay trapped in a constant flow so the electrons keep getting recycled?

Comment: Super-conductor.

Comment: Or a circuit that does 0 work, but whats the point in that?

Comment: Cant have a perpetual motion machine, need an energy source to keep the machine running, the electrons flowing, when the battery runs out, its chemical energy source has balanced such that it can no longer pump electrons around the loop so they stop.  Supposedly you can take some circuits near/to zero kelvin and they will continue to spin with the source removed, but how would you measure that without affecting the loop, and you couldnt sustain that indefinitely.  You are using a lot of energy to keep it that cold so it isnt necessarily perpetual motion.

Comment: You understand open vs closed circuits yes?  For the circuit to work the light bulb to be on, it has to be a closed loop.  The electrons leaving the battery/energy source, like a bucket brigade, kick electrons off the next atom in the loop, but for it to work the whole loop is doing this all the way around at the "speed of light through that medium" so some number of inches  per nanosecond.  If you open the loop, even with a very powerful energy source, the electrons stop flowing.

Comment: Its energy that runs out (which is needed to **move** the electrons)- not the electrons themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The electrons do remain 'trapped' in the battery and conductors - they aren't lost, they simply stop moving when the battery dies.  The battery is like a pump circulating the electrons through the circuit and back to the battery.  What you are asking for is a perpetual energy source, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought maybe the electrons leaked out and that what causes the battery to die.

Comment: No, just the chemicals in the batteries stopping the reactions which cause the electron flow.